# Mysql: Put output of select as new column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have mysql table

> surname | name | complete

Now i want to connect "surname" and "name" with a SELECT CONCAT and put the output into the "complete" column.

Any Idea?

Comment: What's the expected result if surname or name is null?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this the answer by @scaisEdge shows you how. But you really shouldn't! To do so would mean to introduce redunancy. That means your database wouldn't properly normalized. As a rule, you do not store data that is the result of a simple operation on one or more columns.

Consider using a VIEW instead.

```
CREATE VIEW extended_table AS SELECT surname, name, CONCAT(name,surname) AS complete
```

This does not have any storage overhead. Alternatively you can use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html).

```
ALTER TABLE users add column complete as CONCAT(name, surname);
```

Both these options allow you to maintain your table in it's normalized form and you are not saving any redundant data to disk.

@jarlh has raised a very valid point in the comments, how to deal with null

```
CREATE VIEW extended_table AS SELECT surname, name, CONCAT(COALESCE(name,''),COALESCE(surname,'')) AS complete
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use update

```
update my_table 
set complete = concat(surname, name)
```